# CreateFile / readfile & writefile multi threading - invalid handle

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

I dont understand why this dont working:

```
void __cdecl main_pipe_client(void * Args)
{

py_func python_func;

BOOL bRet;
DWORD size = 0;

hpipe = CreateFile(TEXT("D:/stc_5010"), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN, NULL);
if (hpipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    // its OK there is no error
}
while (1)
{
    char wiadomosc[50];
    bRet = ReadFile(hpipe, wiadomosc, 50, &size, NULL);
    //READING ONLINE
    if (bRet == FALSE)
    {
        python_func.py_AppendChat(1, 1, "Read Failed : Bytes Read : %u", size);
        break;
    }
    if (size > 0){
        // There is OK
    }

    Sleep(1500);
    size = 0;
}
}
```

hpipe - is declared at the beginning of program HANDLE hpipe;

```
void init(){
    Sleep(500);
    py_func python_func;
    char buf[256];
    DWORD wpisano = 0;
    sprintf_s(buf, "INIT_CHARACTER");
    if (!WriteFile(hpipe, buf, 256, &wpisano, NULL)){
        char buf5[256];
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, GetLastError(),
            MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), buf5, 256, NULL);
        sprintf_s(buf5, "%s %d", buf5, GetLastError());
        MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCSTR)buf5, (LPCSTR) "ERROR", NULL); // return error 6
    }

}
```

But if i make in loop while, in main_pipe_client function writefile this is fine. And data is written to file.
But if i use this func init() after

```
HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthread(main_pipe_client, 0, NULL);
```

Then writefile return invalid handle...

Comment: Why these casts in the MessageBoxA() call? They look useless.

Comment: `// its OK there is no error`.  Not on this planet.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating the pipe inside a thread, the hpipe HANDLE might not be valid when WriteFile() is invoked. you need to 'synchronize' the threads for this to work properly.

create a [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) say "MyPipeCreateEvent" which will be set by the `main_pipe_client()` after doing a successful `CreateFile()`. in your `init()`, `WaitForSingleobject()` on the "MyPipeCreateEvent" and proceed to WriteFile only when the event is set.